# Android ADB Shell sendevent Not Working

Tags: linux, shell, android, kernel

I want to simulate pressing the power button on a rooted `Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 GT-P5100` running Android 4.0.4 using the ADB shell.

To do this I changed the relevant permissions using:

```
adb shell
su
chmod 666 /dev/input/event1
```

**How do I know whether this was successful?**

I thought that the following command would display the lock screen:

```
input keyevent 116
```

I get no errors, but nothing happens...

Alternatively I used the text form of the key code which looks like this:

```
input keyevent KEY_POWER
```

In this case, the output is `Killed` - **What does this mean?**

Lastly, I tried:

```
sendevent dev/input/event1 1 116 1 ; sendevent dev/input/event1 1 116 0
```

With no luck :(

**What am I doing wrong?**

```
getevent -i /dev/input/event1
```

outputs the following:

```
add device 1: /dev/input/event1
  bus:      0000
  vendor:   0000
  product:  0000
  version:  0000
  name:     "sec_key"
  location: ""
  id:       ""
  version:  1.0.1
  events:
    KEY (0001):  0072  0073  0074
  input props:
    <none>
```

The key `0074` has the textual label `KEY_POWER`.

Answer (score 3):

Power button press consists of a few events.
You can check it by typing command:

```
adb shell getevent -l
```

and then press power button.
On nexus 5 emulator the result is:

```
/dev/input/event0: EV_KEY KEY_POWER   DOWN                
/dev/input/event0: EV_SYN SYN_REPORT  00000000            
/dev/input/event0: EV_KEY KEY_POWER   UP                  
/dev/input/event0: EV_SYN SYN_REPORT  00000000
```

The touch event input file  /dev/input/event can be deferent from device to device. 
In this case it is event0.

Before writing events to device you have to change mode of touch event file:

```
adb shell
chmod 666 /dev/input/event0
```

All definitions of keys can be found in 
http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/prebuilts/ndk/6/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/input.h

The value of sendevent keys should be **decimal**

To emulate the power button press you have to write all those
events :

```
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1  116  108                
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 0  0    0            
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1  116  103                  
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 0  0    0
```

I tested it on Nexus 5 emulator and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not sending in the right way. It's not enough to send only

```
sendevent dev/input/event1 1 116 1 ; sendevent dev/input/event1 1 116 0
```

Please just try the below one ;)

```
sendevent dev/input/event1 1 116 1 ; sendevent dev/input/event1 0 0 0 ;sendevent dev/input/event1 1 116 0 ;sendevent dev/input/event1 0 0 0
```